# How to create a LocalDB on Visual Studio 2013 that doesn't require SQL Server installed

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

I want to create a project that needs Database but I dont want any db server have to be installed on both developer computer and clients.

How can I achieve this, which is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of LocalDB, use SQL Server Compact Edition. You can "bin deploy" that. Just set the references to copy local and it can run without installing anything.

See also:

- http://tech.aendeavors.com/2011/06/09/bin-deploy-sqlce-4-0-and-ef-4-1/

You can download the binaries from the [Microsoft Download site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709). And here is an [explanation on how to create a `.sdf` file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2007/03/31/creating-your-sql-server-compact-edition-database-and-schema-in-code.aspx). And the [SQL Server CE Toolbox is a set of add-ons for Visual Studio that helps you manage SQL Server CE database](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/).

Comment: I can't see it on vs2013 add item section. And what about SQlite

Comment: Added additional information on using SQLCE with VS2013. And yes, you could also use SQL Lite.

Comment: Which one do you advice

Comment: I have no preference. Try them and see what works best for you.

Comment: Does this compose well with deploying to SQL on Azure?  Why wouldn't you just use localDB and migrations?

Comment: For Azure I'd use SQL Azure and would never use locally stored LocalDB's or SQL CE. Though the VM image has a number of guarantees, it s databases can get corrupted if it needs to be restarted, moved etc.  Azure offers EF-Migrations on AzureDB/SQLAzure, why not use it.

Comment: SQL CE is deprecated. I do not believe Microsoft has a supported standalone database file anymore. I mean, other then Access.